# How can I protect ClickOnce application from uninstall?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, clickonce, uninstallation

I've a ClickOnce application that once installed on a Standard User account can be uninstalled by users other than the Administrator(s). Is it possible to make the application require Admin privilege to uninstall the ClickOnce? How?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want this? The protocol is designed to be light, admin privileges are not required for installation, it would be wierd to require them for uninstall, also the app can be easily installed again if it is removed.

Comment: in my case, I don't want users to have the privilege to install/uninstall but I want the automatic update feature

Comment: Then I would say you need to build a traditional install package and have the install check for updates. Otherwise you are going against the grain of both ClickOnce and Windows.